# Can't establish a connection to the database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, bukkit

I'm currently trying to develop a Minecraft-plugin for Bukkit.

This is the code of my Database class:

```
package net.klapsenjesus.protoncore;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import static org.bukkit.Bukkit.getLogger;

public class Database {
    Connection connection;

    public Database() {

    }

    public boolean connect (String host, String database, String user, String password) {

        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            String connectionCommand = "jdbc:mysql://"+host+"/"+database+"?user="+user+"&password="+password+"&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10";
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionCommand);
            getLogger().info("Die Datenbankverbindung wurde erfolgreich hergestellt.");
            return true;

        }catch (Exception ex){


            System.out.println(ex);
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

I'm calling it from my main-class in the following way:

```
String[] data = new String[4];

data[0] = getConfig().getString("host");
data[1] = getConfig().getString("database");
data[2] = getConfig().getString("user");
data[3] = getConfig().getString("password");
```

In my my.cnf i set the bind-adress to 0.0.0.0, the firewall isn't blocking any requests, MySQL is up and running. I don't have any idea where the error is.

Here's the exception:

> Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 10
> times. Giving up. 15:58:56 WARN:    at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:403) 15:58:56 WARN:
> at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386) 15:58:56 WARN:
> at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2095)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2020)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:768)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:403) 15:58:56 WARN:
> at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:385)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:323)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664) 15:58:56
> WARN:    at
> java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270) 15:58:56
> WARN:    at
> net.klapsenjesus.protoncore.Database.connect(Database.java:20)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> net.klapsenjesus.protoncore.ProtonCore.onEnable(ProtonCore.java:34)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:263)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:351)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:480)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:494)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:408)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.reload(CraftServer.java:881)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:651)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:27)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:149)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:763)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:748)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer.handleCommandQueue(DedicatedServer.java:387)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer.b(DedicatedServer.java:356)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:1008)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:847)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:164)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 15:58:56
> WARN: Caused by:
> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
> Communications link failure 15:58:56 WARN:  15:58:56 WARN: The
> last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
> The driver has not received any packets from the server. 15:58:56
> WARN:    at
> sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor24.newInstance(Unknown Source)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:403) 15:58:56 WARN:
> at
> com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:990)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:335)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2187)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2036)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  ... 31 more 15:58:56 WARN: Caused by:
> java.net.UnknownHostException: null 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1281) 15:58:56
> WARN:    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at
> java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127) 15:58:56
> WARN:    at
> com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:188)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:299)
> 15:58:56 WARN:  ... 33 more

Comment: `java.net.UnknownHostException: null` suggests that the value of `host` is `null` (or `"null"`), which suggests that your config doesn't have the property `host` (and maybe others) or that your calling your method incorrectly (you don't actually show how you call connect). You may want to debug your code, for example by adding `System.out.println(host)` in your connect method (or checking the variables in the debugger of your IDE) and then tracing back why it doesn't have the value you expect.

Comment: I'm reading all this stuff from the config.yml.
"host: localhost" - Do i need to use quotes?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. And double check that your config is actually loaded as you expect.

Comment: It is. I've tested.

Comment: Then you aren't passing those values to the `Database.connect` method, otherwise it wouldn't have produced a `java.net.UnknownHostException: null` message.